# Upgrading to mainline kernel 5.9 with ZFS (on 20.10)

Tags: kernel, zfs, 20.10

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 on a new machine with the ZFS option, i. e. both `/boot` and the root file system are on ZFS. However, I need the newer kernel version 5.9 for hardware support, which I installed using the [mainline kernel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.8/). Unfortunately, [the version of ZFS included in Ubuntu 20.10 (v0.8.4)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/zfs-dkms) doesn’t work with Linux v5.9 kernels (building the kernel module fails).

This leads to quite the predicament: How can I use both the required newer kernel version and ZFS (of course, including full functionality, such as ZSys)?

- I’ve tried [building and installing ZFS from source](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Developer%20Resources/Building%20ZFS.html). However, the [`.deb` packages created when building ZFS from source are incompatible with Ubuntu’s packages](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10329#issuecomment-628817428), and thus anything that depends on the Ubuntu packages ([like ZSys!](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/zsys)) falls victim to the package conflicts and has to be removed/cannot be installed.
- Due to these problems, I noticed that current [Debian bullseye (testing) has newer packages with version 0.8.5 of ZFS (which is compatible with Linux v5.9)](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/zfs-dkms), and the packaging scheme looks compatible with the one in Ubuntu. So I tried upgrading to these packages, and building the kernel modules for my mainline 5.9.8 kernel did indeed succeed. However, on boot, this fails to mount the ZFS file system  (even with the normal 5.8 Ubuntu kernel):

  ```
  Command: mount -o zfsutil -t zfs rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_682y7z /root//
  Message: filesystem 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_682y7z' can not be mounted: Permission denied
  ```

So, now I’m stuck. What is the most robust way of running a mainline kernel which also requires upgrading ZFS? I did consider building a custom 5.9 kernel with built-in ZFS support, but wouldn’t the ZFS version in my kernel then conflict with the installed Ubuntu packages, which use an older version of ZFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that, while the [version of the ZFS packages in the Ubuntu development version (hirsute) is currently `0.8.4-1ubuntu13`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux), the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/0.8.4-1ubuntu13) shows the following:

> ### Changelog
>
> ```
> zfs-linux (0.8.4-1ubuntu13) hirsute; urgency=medium
>
>   * Add Linux 5.9 compat fixes (LP: #1899826)
>     - 4800-Linux-5.9-compat-add-linux-blkdev.h-include.patch
>       include blkdev.h in various sources
>     - 4801-Linux-5.9-compat-NR_SLAB_RECLAIMABLE.patch
>       deprecate some older page free stats for arc free page calculation
>     - 4802-Linux-5.9-compat-make_request_fn-replaced-with-submi.patch
>       API change for block allocation
>     - 4805-Increase-Supported-Linux-Kernel-to-5.9.patch
>       allows driver to be built against 5.9
>   * Add Linux 5.10 compat fixes
>     - 4710-Use-percpu_counter-for-obj_alloc-counter-of-Linux-ba.patch
>       prerequisite for 4804-Linux-5.10-compat-frame.h-renamed-objtool.h.patch
>     - 4720-Linux-5.7-compat-Include-linux-sched.h-in-spl-sys-mu.patch
>       prerequisite for next set of patches
>     - 4804-Linux-5.10-compat-frame.h-renamed-objtool.h.patch
>       rename check of linux/frame.h to linux/frame.h
>     - 4805-Linux-5.10-compat-percpu_ref-added-data-member.patch
>       API check to the percpu_ref structure
>     - 4806-Linux-5.10-compat-check_disk_change-removed.patch
>       check_disk_change removed, functionality moved to zfs_check_media_change
>     - 4807-Linux-5.10-compat-revalidate_disk_size-added.patch
>       use revalidate_disk_size where necessary
>
>  -- Colin Ian King <colin.king@canonical.com>  Tue, 3 Nov 2020 12:22:22 +0000
> ```

which indicates that the required changes for compatibility with newer Linux kernels have been backported to these packages. So I installed the `zfs-dkms` package from the `hirsute` repositories, which gave me a working DKMS ZFS module with my mainline kernel.